# How to reduce duplicating in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, code-duplication

I have started learning Java recently and my question might be stupid, but nevertheless:

I'm working on small project, for now it's just a simple web-service, working on Google App Engine.
We aew using JSPs like this.

View - jsp file

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="my.package.web.SpecificBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="request" value="<%=request%>" />
```

Controller - java bean.

```
public class SpecificBean {
    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        /*
        Do authorization
        Prepare data for page
        */
    }
}
```

> ---ADDED--- for the first time it was hidden

`<jsp:setProperty` calls setRequest method, it prepares data for page, and I'm using JSTL to put this data in necessary places.
Controller using domain & etc., but that is not what I'm talking about.
When I add authorization, I decide not to redirect people, but to give them login page on the this address.
I wrote smth like that:

> ---/ADDED---

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="my.package.web.SpecificBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="request" value="<%=request%>" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${!bean.userAuth.loggedIn}">
        <html><head><title>Please log in</title></head><body>...</body></html>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${!bean.userAuth.userValid}">
        <html><head><title>You are not allowed</title></head><body>...</body></html>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <html><head><title>Page you have been requested</title></head><body>...</body></html>
    </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

Yeah, that looks bulky, I know! In every `.jsp` I have to copy-paste such a big piece of code.
Of course I made some improvements, like put "Please log in" html into separate `.jsp` and used `<%@include file=""%>`
But anyway there is a decent piece of code, that wrapping every page. There are only 3 pages, but...
I could use two `<%@include file=""%>` instructions, for "head" and "bottom", but I'm not sure this decision has no bad consequences.

So my what should I do?

1. Use just `<%@include file=""%>`
2. Redirect (but I think it's not the last problem of my architecture)
3. I heard about Spring Web Flow, guess it's what I need. However it could be overkill for a small web-service
4. Use taglib and make my own tags, using them like JSTL
5. Your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Authentication is not something your page should know about or consider.

Move this logic into a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that checks the authentication and redirects if needed.

Comment: @AlexB Well, you will have several controllers, but only one point of authentication (and/or authorization).  So I wouldn't call it ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Simple go for  a dynamic include:

```
<jsp:include page="pagename" />
```

The  `<jsp:include`  action is executed at request time  where  as the  `<%@include` executes the compile time.

Comment: What's the difference of the `includes` in this situation? There will be same coping of code.

Comment: A dynamic include executes the included page and includes the result in the output of the current page. A static include adds the contents of the included page to the source of the current page before the current page is compiled. There is only copying for static includes.